# I need help passing a variable from a link into a function using defining a global variable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, freemarker

Forgive me for my wording but this is the first time that I've written anything like this

I'm passing a freeMarker variable into a JQuery function on click of a link

```
<a onclick="showDisclaimer('${item.uid}')">Read the blog</a>
```

The variable passes fine but what I would like to do is show a hidden modal when the link is clicked. The name of the hidden modal is

```
<div class="disclaimer ${item.uid}" style="display:none;">
```

The code does not seem to be working. For one, I would like to define a global variable so that both functions have access to. As you can see I'm defining var x = uid; twice.

Also in my code $('body').append($('div.disclaimer x').remove()); does not work and I figure that it's because I haven't passed the variable yet or created a global variable. I just don't know how to do it.

My code is below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

```
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"content":"http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/","dc":"http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"}>

    <script>
      // Forces the disclaimer component to load on the body

      $('body').append($('div.disclaimer x').remove());

      function showDisclaimer (uid) { 
        var x = uid;
        $('div.disclaimer x').show();

      }

      function closeDisclaimer(uid) {
        var x = uid;
        // Clear the form and close the modal
        $('div.disclaimer x').hide();
      }
    </script>  


    <section style="background-color: #ededed">
      <section class="head-transit">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row-fluid">

          <#list kiblogs.rss.channel.item as item>
              <div class="span4">
                <div class="panel">
                  <img src="${item.thumbnail.@@nested_markup}" class="title-image"> 
                    <div class="top-content">
                      <h3>${item.title}</h3>
                      <div class="datetime">${item.pubDate}</div>
                      <div class="analyst"></div>
                      <p class="test">${item.description}</p>                  
                    </div>

                    <div class="disclaimer ${item.uid}" style="display:none;">
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="close"><a href="#" onclick="closeDisclaimer()">x</a></div>
                          <h3>${item.title}</h3>
                          <div class="datetime">${item.pubDate}</div>
                          <p class="test">${item.description}</p>
                           <p class="${item.uid}">Hey now</p>  
                          <div class="divider"></div>                      
                      </div>
                    </div> 

                    <div class="bottom-content">
                    <div class="bottom-blue-buttn"><a onclick="showDisclaimer('${item.uid}')">Read the blog</a></div>
                   </div>
                </div>
               </div> 
                <div class="disclaimer ${item.uid}" style="display:none;">
                  <div class="content">
                    <div class="close"><a href="#" onclick="closeDisclaimer()">x</a></div>
                      <h3 class="title2"></h3> 
                      <div class="divider"></div>
                      <p class="content2"></p>

                  </div>
                </div>            
            <hr>            
          </#list>

          </div>
       </div>
      </section>
    </section>
```

I got the code to work but now I am getting a Console error that uid is not defined in var outerVar = uid; but uid is defined within my first and second function.

In my first line of code

```
      var outerVar = uid;

      $('body').append($('div.disclaimer' + outerVar).remove());

      function showDisclaimer (uid) { 
        var x = uid;
        $('div.disclaimer' + x).show();

      }

      function closeDisclaimer(uid) {
        var x = uid;
        // Clear the form and close the modal
        $('div.disclaimer' + x).hide();
      }


    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The css selector is wrong. You need to concatenate the x variable.

```
      function showDisclaimer (uid) { 
        var x = uid;
        $('div.disclaimer' + x).show();

      }

      function closeDisclaimer(uid) {
        var x = uid;
        // Clear the form and close the modal
        $('div.disclaimer' + x).hide();
      }
```

Example to reuse variables:

```
var outside = 'Fooo!';
function foo () { 
    console.log(outSide); //output 'Fooo!'
}

function bar() {
    var inside = 'Hello';
    console.log(inside); //output 'Hello'
}

console.log(inside); //output undefined
```

For more info on:
[What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to use 'x' variable in the class name below even though it's above my function? $('body').append($('div.disclaimer').remove());

Comment: `x` is `uid` which is passed as parameter to the functions. `onclick="showDisclaimer('${item.uid}')`. In this case `uid = ${item.uid}`. It's different for each one. Why do you want to make it static?

Comment: Ahhh, I see so will  $('body').append($('div.disclaimer x').remove()); work even though (uid) is passed in a function below it?

Comment: If you have a variable set in the outer scope you will be able to access it inside the functions.  Be careful, in your last example you have the css selector wrong again. `$('body').append($('div.disclaimer' +  outerVar).remove());` If this was the correct answer could you mark it please. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated my answer. Although I am able to access the outside variable. It's not defined. I would like for the outside variable to use the same value that is being passed to my function onclick

Comment: No problem. I updated my question and placed it here. Please take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30647347/having-issues-using-a-scope-in-jquery

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79681/discussion-between-andybeli-and-jimmy).