# Having issues using a scope in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

So I'm trying to pass a freemarker variable value (${item.uid}) on the click of a link in order to launch a modal with the same unique id value.

Although my functions can access the value of `uid`, when I run `$('body').append($('div.disclaimer' + outerVar).remove());` the `outerVar` shows `undefined`.

**JavaScript**

```
var outerVar = uid;
$('body').append($('div.disclaimer' + outerVar).remove());

function showDisclaimer(uid) {
    var x = uid;
    $('div.disclaimer' + x).show();
}

function closeDisclaimer(uid) {
    var x = uid;
    // Clear the form and close the modal
    $('div.disclaimer' + x).hide();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<a onclick="showModal('${item.uid}')">Call Function</a>
<div class="modal${item.uid}" style="display:none;">
    <div class="content">
        Test Content Here
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: From the code you provided, `uid` is undefined at the time you declare `outerVar`, hence why it returns `undefined`.

Comment: .disclaimer + 'anything' doesn't exist anywhere in your html. uid is not defined at the point you init outerVar. I don't get whay tou are setting outerVar at all... since uid I presume is some kind of global reference.

Comment: @Jeff Your right it is a global reference. uid has a variable value but is there away for me to pass it to outerVar?

Comment: Going strictly from the code provided, there's no reason to create `outerVar` at all. Anything that can access it can also access `uid`

Comment: Also no reason at all for `var x = uid` in the functions.

Comment: But is there a code example or a way to pass uid to $('body').append($('div.disclaimer' + ... ?

Comment: I don't understand what the code is supposed to be doing, but yes, `uid` should be available to `$('body').append()`. Here's a [very simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4nypukf4/). And are you trying to append an element you just removed? I really don't get that part.

Comment: I'm updating some code someone gave me. I tested it and it works. I believe $('body').append($('div.disclaimer' + outerVar).remove()); is an overlay div that displays on top of the screen